# How to display custom taxonomy term meta on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I am new to custom taxonomies, and created a taxonomy with 3 term meta fields using the generator on wp-hasty.com

The taxonomy and new fields show up properly on the back end, and I am able to save to them.

My problem is displaying them on the front end.

I have a custom post type named "paint", and my taxonomy is named "colors", and the term meta fields are named "blue", "red", and "green". The term meta fields are regular text fields with text in them.

I would like to display the contents of "blue", "red", and "green" on my custom post type page, if the page has the taxonomy tag colors.

Online I found `get_term_meta()`, but I couldn't get it right.

I appreciate all help. Please let me know if I'm not being clear enough with my question.

Comment: When you say "term meta fields" I'm not clear what you mean. Are these like text fields with values in them, or do you just mean that "blue", "red", and "green" are choices of colour? I'm just not clear what's supposed to be 'meta'.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The term meta fields are regular text fields with text in them.

Comment: Please check this: [How to show taxonomy meta on frontpage?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106953/how-to-show-taxonomy-meta-on-frontpage?rq=1)

Comment: @Michael Thanks, but unfortunately that did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** If you need to display this informations once. For example in the page header, use [get_queried_object()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object).

```
echo get_term_meta( get_queried_object()->term_id, 'blue', true );
echo get_term_meta( get_queried_object()->term_id, 'red', true );
echo get_term_meta( get_queried_object()->term_id, 'green', true );
```

**2.** If you need to display this informations in the each post, you must create a small loop.

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'colors');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    echo get_term_meta( $term_id, 'blue', true );
    echo get_term_meta( $term_id, 'red', true );
    echo get_term_meta( $term_id, 'green', true );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found that earlier, and I just don't know how to use it. My post type is "paint", my taxonomy is "colors" and my term meta field is "blue". How do I plug that in?

Comment: f you need to display this informations once. For example in the page header, use get_queried_object().  If you need to display this informations in the each post, you must create a small loop. Updated answer.

Comment: Your'e a life saver! Thanks so much for a clear and concise answer.